# Flying-saucer/iText PDF not finding css file

Tags: css, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I can generate a PDF using flying-saucer/iText. However, I can't figure out how to get the style sheet included in the PDF rendering.

I have used this [flying-saucer/iText PDF in servlet not finding css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722038/flying-saucer-itext-pdf-in-servlet-not-finding-css-file?rq=1) as reference.

There are multiple css files involved so I won't be able to use `renderer.setDocument(doc, "http://example.com/something/page.html");`
as a solution

I have implemented a something similar to what the asker used, but it's returning a `Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http://localhost:8080/proj/resources/css/custom1.css` error

Here is my code

```
      StringBuilder bui = new StringBuilder();
      bui.append("<html><head><style>");
      bui.append(readFile(path+"/resources/css/custom1.css", Charsets.UTF_8));
      bui.append(readFile(path+"/resources/css/custom2.css", Charsets.UTF_8));
      bui.append(readFile(path+"/resources/css/custom3.css", Charsets.UTF_8));

      bui.append("</style></head>");
      bui.append("<body><div><table>");
      bui.append( xhtml_file );
      bui.append("</table></div></body></html>");

      InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bui.toString().getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ));
      Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(stream, null);
      File outputFile = new File(directory+ "FILENAME" +".pdf");
      os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
      renderer.layout();
      renderer.createPDF(os, false);
      renderer.finishPDF();
```

the path being passed is "http://localhost:8080"
if I enter "http://localhost:8080/resources/css/custom1.css" directly into the address bar, it shows the css file. I tried removing the 'path' but it's also not getting the css. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the file:/// url protocol to point (with three slashes) pointing to the css file directly.